# Recipients.Count in VB not working

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin

I have a Outlook add-in in which I am trying to access recipients of the Appointment invite. Even though the recipients column is null, the code `Outlook.AppointmentItem.Recipients.Count` returns 1, and `Recipients` returns the sender's email.

```
 Dim recips As Outlook.Recipients
 Dim recip As Outlook.Recipient
 Dim flag As Boolean = False

 cal = Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem
 recips = cal.Recipients
 cal.Save()
 MessageBox.Show(recips.Count)
 For Each recip In recips
     MessageBox.Show(recip.Address)
 Next
```

Can anyone suggest why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [GetAssociatedAppointment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/meetingitem-getassociatedappointment-method-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1455)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which returns an `AppointmentItem` object that represents the appointment associated with the meeting request. Then you may use the following properties:

- [RequiredAttendees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/appointmentitem-requiredattendees-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm898)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) - returns a semicolon-delimited String of required attendee names for the meeting appointment.
- [OptionalAttendees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/appointmentitem-optionalattendees-property-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm888)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) - returns or sets a String representing the display string of optional attendees names for the appointment.

And of course the `Recipients` property of the AppointmentItem class.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design - the appointment organizer is always in the recipient table. You can figure out who the organizer is by looking at the `PR_RECIPIENT_FLAGS` property (DALS name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5FFD0003`) using `Recipient.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. The organizer will have `recipOrganizer` ( = 2) bit set.

Comment: I swear I came across a situation recently where Recipients.Count was 0 for Outlook 2013, but 1 for 2016. I had to deliberately code to accommodate this

Comment: Yes, older versions of Outlook had no recipients and no global appointment id until the appointment is saved. Outlook 2016 adds the organizer as recipient as soon as Save is called.